# Classification framework for sparse binary vectors as input and output

Tags: classification, neural-networks, cart, binary-data

I have a dataset where the input and output are both $2500$ dimensional binary vectors. The input and output feature components have a 1-to-1 mapping, i.e. component $n$ ($1 \leq n \leq 2500)$ of the feature vector has the same interpretation for input and output. Also, each component indicates presence or absence of a binary visual attribute (e.g. whether a particular object is present in the image or absent). The input and output vectors arise from detecting these attributes from two different modalities (e.g. run object detector on color image for input, run a different kind of object detector on depth image for output).

The binary vectors are very sparse -- on average, less than $10\%$ of the vectors are non-zeros.

I have about $200,000$ such input-output pairs and wish to train a classification model such that given an input binary vector, I would like to predict the output binary vector as accurately as possible. I have tried Decision Trees and a variety of Multi Layer Neural Networks. However, I am unable to go beyond an accuracy of $30\%$.

Any suggestions for this scenario ?

Comment: Can you tell us what these binary vectors represent, and what is your goal?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Added some detail. Does that help ?